# bootstrap navbar how to give it a max width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't get this to work.

I've got a nav bar

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="pull-right">
        <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Nieuwe medewerker</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now this is a nice bar width the width of the container, it's centered in the middle, exactly how I want it.

Now I want this exact bar to be fixed to bottom, however when I add navbar-fixed-bottom, it automatically stretches to my window size.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom">
```

I've been trying to adjust the css but can't get it to work. Someone has a idea of how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `navbar-fixed-bottom` uses `position:fixed` so it's removed from the flow of the page and no longer takes the width of it's container.

You could instead make another class (ie; navbar-bottom) and use position absolute to place it on the bottom...

```
.navbar-bottom {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:90%;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/126172